# Feature request: "intuitive" tag

Tags: feature-request, tags

I come to see many questions which in essence mostly ask for some intuition about a concept. Actually, I would argue that most of the top questions on this site could be considered intuition question, for instance [this one](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/5706/what-is-the-dying-relu-problem-in-neural-networks)

I think that an "intuitive" tag would be a great complement to a tag like "math". This would allow users that aren't as mathematically inclined to focus on providing answers on questions with the "intuitive" tag.

This question actually because of [this post](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/64570/does-this-line-in-python-indicate-that-knn-is-weighted/64573?noredirect=1#comment69798_64573). OP wants a mathematical answer but it isn't clear from the post at first. After a few comments, I edited the post to make this more obvious.

Comment: Why would a math based answer be low quality simple because the OP was hoping for an intuitive answer?

Comment: I edited the question since it was evidently not as clear as I thought. Math based answers are always high quality. Intuitive answers may not always be desired